# A firm employes 26 designers, 21 accountants and 11 scientists. Find the probability that it contains employees of exactly two of these professions

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

A firm employes 26 designers, 21 accountants and 11 scientists.

Let us now select 7 employees at random to serve on a committee. Find the probability that it contains employees of exactly two of these professions. (F.x one or more designers and one or more accountants but no scientist.) Show a formula.

What would be the best way to solve this? i've been stuck on this problem for a while.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Find the probability that it contains no designers.  Find the probability that it contains no designers *and* no accountants (*i.e. contains only scientists*).  Find the probability that it contains no designers *and* no scientists (*i.e. contains only accountants*).  Using these three pieces of information you should be able to find the probability that you contain no designers, at least one accountant, and at least one scientist.  Repeat the process twice more to find the probability of at least one designer no accountants and at least one scientist and so on and reach final conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $58$ persons, and one can form $c:={58\choose7}$ different 7sets from them, all of them assumed equiprobable. When we form the sum
$$a:={26+21\choose7}+{26+11\choose7}+{21+11\choose7}$$
we have counted the 7sets containing at most two kinds of employees. In this way the ${26\choose7}$ 7sets containing, e.g., only designers have been counted twice, but they should not be counted at all. We therefore form the sum
$$b:={26\choose7}+{21\choose7}+{11\choose7}\ ,$$
which represents the number of all 7sets containing only one kind of employee.

The desired probability then is given by
$$p={a-2b\over c}={5769539\over23128776}=0.249453\ .$$

Comment: I really appreciate your help @christian-blatter. Thank you.